# foundation 5 center align top bar

Tags: html, css, alignment, zurb-foundation

[image: top-bar problem]

i can't seem to align the top bar with the rest of the content. i had it for a sec when i took the section out of the nav and put row large-12 around it, but then it wasn't fixed and when i added fixed it left aligned it but it was still the size i needed. i tried margin: 0 auto; and that didn't work either. so now i'm stumped.

```
/* TOP BAR */
.top-bar {
    background-color: #cc0b12;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 200;
}
.top-bar-section .has-form {
    background-color: #cc0b12;
}
.headerbar {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.redbar {
    z-index: 300;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
input[type="text"] {
    margin-top: 6px;
    height: 31px;
    font-family: Lato;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -28px;
}
.magglass {
    height: 15px;
    margin-left: -23px;
    margin-top: 13px;
}
.top-bar input {
    position: static;
    margin-top: 7px;
}
.help {
    margin-top: -40px;
    float: right;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    margin-right: -23px;
}
.help a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-size: .9em;
}
.cart {
    float: right;
    width: 22px;
    padding-top: 6px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
/* /TOP BAR */

<div class="headerbar">
<div class="row hide-for-small fixed redbar">
<div class="large-12">
<section class="top-bar-section">

<!-- search bar -->
<div class="has-form">
  <div class="row collapse">
    <div class="large-3 small-4 columns">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
      <a href="#"><img src="img/magglass.png" class="magglass"/></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /search bar -->

<div class="right">
  <div class="help">
    <!-- set backwards for right float -->
    <a href="#">CART (0)</a><img src="img/cart.png" class="cart"/>
    <a href="#">LOG IN</a><img src="img/login.png" class="cart"/>
    <a href="#">HELP CENTER</a><img src="img/HelpCenter.png" class="cart"/>
  </div><!-- /help -->
</div><!-- /right -->

</section>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What _exactly_ is your requirement? Do you want to: (a) Center the icons (help center, log in, cart) to the remaining red area that is not occupied by the `search box` of the `top bar`; or (b) center these icons on the `top bar` with the whole `top bar` area (_including_ the space occupied by the `search box`)

Comment: make the stuff in the red bar align the same with the rest of the content on the page, responsivly so the search bar will stilll be left and the other stuff will still be right but have the same left and right margin spacing as the stuff below it.

Answer (score 0):

```
.large-12 {
    background-color: #cc0b12;
}
.top-bar-section {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: nope. unfortunatly it just moved the search bar slightly to the right instead of all the top content. i tried playing with the % and it just didn't work, but thank you for trying!